# SymmetricDS : transform column on EXTERNAL_ID

Tags: synchronization, symmetricds

I have a scenario where I sync PLU table to all stores (HQ -> Store). But my cost and price column will take specifically for each store based on value on a reference table. So, the same PLU might get different cost and price for each store. I try on lookup column transformation but it did not work on the EXTERNAL_ID. How can I make this scenario works ?

Eg.

Source Table (HQ) : PLU

Source Column : plucode, name, cost, price

---

Reference Table (HQ) : PLUPrice

Source Column : storecode, plucode, cost, price

---

Target Table (STORE) : PLU

Target Column : plucode, name, cost, price

```
insert into SYM_TRANSFORM_COLUMN (transform_id, include_on, target_column_name, source_column_name, pk, transform_type, transform_expression, transform_order, last_update_time, last_update_by, create_time) values (
    'plu', '*', 'cost', 'cost', 0,
    'lookup', 'SELECT cost FROM PLUPrice WHERE PLUCODE = :PLUCODE AND STORECODE = :EXTERNAL_ID', 1, current_timestamp, 'Administrator', current_timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a routing on the reference table. If one of the columns contains the externalId then make it column based routing, otherwise subselect routing.

Comment: Before that I synced two tables separately to one table, by excluding the cost & price in the source table, and take the cost & price from reference table. This is OK but there is one issue during reload, sometime if reference table is missed out then data will be out of sync. So I was thinking to only sync one table in the question but no success. I try to use virtual column concept too but no success. Any idea if this is work ?

Comment: Sync to two tables with some other names on the target node using transformation to rename them. Then on the target node create a scheduled task in your application that will periodically check if both tables have synced and copy data to the single table used by the application

Comment: Your suggestion is OK but we do not want to create extra table to handle this. Is it because I have no way to get the EXTERNAL_ID in the select statement ?

Comment: An external_id is required for the routing. Otherwise the syncing is going to be a broadcast

Comment: But this is not about routing. Routing is to route all data (PLU) from source to target. The thing is I want to check reference table (PLUPrice) to update the table. If not external_id, is there anyway I can get the target node id in select statement ?

Comment: There are two ways to route data. To all nodes (broadcast) or certain data to certain target nodes. It is about routing

Comment: What if I want to force trigger of both tables if I modify at either reference table or source table ? So that my target will get accurate data.